# Changing color and underline the content of link button

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net, vb.net

I would like to change color and underline the content of link button that are placed in datalist's item template only selected button

**Below is my code which is used to set link button**

```
<asp:DataList ID="DlPaging" runat="server" BorderWidth="0" RepeatDirection="Horizontal">
  <ItemTemplate>
     <asp:LinkButton CssClass="pagenav" ID="LnkBtnPage" OnClientClick="clickfire(this.id);" runat="server" Visible="true">
        <%# Container.ItemIndex +1 %>
     </asp:LinkButton>
        <%--   <asp:Label runat="server" ID="LblPage" CssClass="pagenav2" Font-Bold="True" Visible="true"
                       Text='<%# Container.ItemIndex +1 %>'>
               </asp:Label>
        &nbsp;--%>
 </ItemTemplate>
 </asp:DataList>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can easily accomplish what you want using CSS.

```
.pagenav:hover {
    text-decoration: underline;
    color: blue;
}
```

Comment: But i'm using this link button for paging and on click this button page is postback So we cannot retain the CSS style on linkbutton.     @flakomalo

Comment: To select the current link you should use your server-side code to add a class to the link. For instance, add the "selected" class only to the button that was selected. Can you provide the URL and parameters that show when you click on one of the links?